# FBSDKLog: (null) logs and no events in the events manager

Tags: xcode, logging, swiftui, fbsdk

I am making a swift UI app in which I want logs on FB events manager whenever the user taps the button. This is how my code looks like:

```
switch activeAlert {
                                    case .first:
                                    logMyEvent(name:"event",value:"params")
                                    
                                        return Alert(title: Text("Successful Message"), message: Text("Sucessfully Submitted"),
                                            dismissButton: .default(Text("OK!")))
                                    case .second:
                                        return Alert(title: Text("Incorrect Details"), message: Text("Some details is mission or incorrect. Enter details again. "),
                                            dismissButton: .default(Text("OK!")))
                                    }
 private func logMyEvent(name : String, value : String) {
      let params : [String: Any] = ["fields" : "fields"]
      let eventName: AppEvents.Name = AppEvents.Name(rawValue: "myEventName")
      AppEvents.logEvent(eventName, parameters: params)
  }
```

But I am getting these:

```
    2022-03-29 16:11:35.606179+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165553] FBSDKLog: (null)
2022-03-29 16:11:35.606254+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165557] FBSDKLog: (null)
2022-03-29 16:11:35.606269+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165563] FBSDKLog: (null)
2022-03-29 16:11:35.606610+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165557] FBSDKLog: (null)
2022-03-29 16:11:35.763810+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165556] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
2022-03-29 16:11:35.769825+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165556] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
2022-03-29 16:11:35.772329+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165556] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
2022-03-29 16:11:35.774020+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165556] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
2022-03-29 16:12:03.789714+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165396] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
Button Tapped
2022-03-29 16:12:04.413665+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165838] FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /2592252710881090/aem_conversion_configs should contain an explicit "fields" parameter
2022-03-29 16:12:04.414139+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165838] FBSDKLog: (null)
2022-03-29 16:12:04.414278+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165838] FBSDKLog: (null)
2022-03-29 16:12:04.564779+0530 Jivox-ios[11136:165739] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
```

I can't see anything on my Fb events manager and not able to figure out what exactly the problem is.

I want to log events in event manager by launching swiftUI app in xcode, But I didn't receive any logs in event manager of facebook.

Comment: Please post the error logs as text instead of image. Also, post the portion of your source code that may be relevant to the question.

Comment: @WrichikBasu I've updated the question. Can you please check now ?